# Firebase User Auth check in App delegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Firebase Auth and Firebase Database in app delegate which checks if the user is logged in or not.It checks in a 'users' node in Database to see if there is an userid in child snapshots or not and this operation takes about 2-3 seconds.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                print("App Delegate: User found!")
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main")
                self.window?.rootViewController = vc
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
            else{
                print("App Delegate: User not found!")
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login")
                self.window?.rootViewController = vc
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        })
    }
    return true
}
```

The Login viewController is the Initial viewController. When launch screen fades out, the login viewController is show and if the user is logged in, the Main viewController is shown but in this case, there is a time interval of 2-3 secs for which the Login viewController is being shown.
I tried to implement NavigationController too but same problem.

So how can I not show Login viewController if the user is logged in and go straight to the Main viewController and manage that 2-3 time seconds of time interval effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track isLogin variable in local session make it true and false while login and logout successful. When the first login then checks your session variable isLogin. You can save the session in UserDefault or Keychain. This way you can avoid your issue.

Or you just need to check this way:

```
if FIRAuth.auth().currentUser != nil {
   presentHome()
} else {
 //User Not logged in
}
```

After that when you navigated to desire viewController do rest of the things there.